# wildcard character * does not expand in crontab, but runs from terminal

Tags: bash, wildcard, cron

I am trying to run this comamand from bash script through crontab, it just gets SystemOut.log, though I expect to get SystemOut_* as well.

```
/app/hdup/get_logs SystemOut*
```

But when i tried to run this above command from terminal, it worked properly and got both SystemOut.log and SystemOut_*

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: You should look at the default shell Cron uses. You use /bin/bah as your default shell which uses * as you expect. But does the default Cron shell the same thing? The default shell can be found in /etc/passwd. Alternativly you can add something like `/bin/bash /app/hdup/get_logs SystemOut*` to crontab.

Comment: When you run from the terminal, there may be no files that match the pattern, so it is passed literally to your script as a single argument. When `cron` runs is, does it do so from a directory that contains a file `SystemOut.log`? In that case, you script receives the matching file name as an argument, not the shell pattern.

Comment: So how do I enforce, so that it takes as shell pattern

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments already: The `cron` is using a different shell than you do. You can set the shell to be used by cron via a variable at the top of your `crontab` to have the same result as in your terminal:

`SHELL=/bin/bash`

Details can be found at https://serverfault.com/a/678414

Answer (score 1):

cron is executed by /bin/sh which is the key point why many special string like * , {},etc not work.
put SHELL=/bin/bash on the first line of you cron file after "crontab -e"